# Modify order of operations on Django admin pages to populate history tables

Tags: django, django-admin

I've created a very simplistic way to store the history of a Django model:

```
class Estimate(Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def makeHistory(self):
        history = new EstimateHistory()
        history.date = self.date
        history.amount = self.amount
        history.last_mod_date = timezone.now()
        history.last_mod_user = 'username'

class EstimateHistory(Model):
    # Same fields as Estimate...
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    # ...with two more added as History metadata
    last_mod_date = models.DateTimeField("last modified date")
    last_mod_user = 'username'
```

I've overridden the `save()` method of `Model`, to do this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # Is there a history table? Save off the object in it.
        historyObject = self.makeHistory()                             # <-- Line A
        print "Saving " + str(type(self)) + ", in a history table"
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        historyObject.save()
    except AttributeError:
        print "Saving " + str(type(self)) + ", but not in a history table"
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except Error:
        print "Not even saving. Something went wrong."
        raise
```

This seems to work fine, EXCEPT the whole point of storing a history is to store the values BEFORE the object is saved.

I'm using the admin page to test this, yet if I change

```
Date:      2015-01-01
Estimate:  1500.00
```

to

```
Date:      2015-01-01
Estimate:  1700.00
```

the value of `self.amount` is 1700.00 during the call to `makeHistory()` at Line A above. That is, the admin page is changing the currently loaded model before it's persisted in the database.

How can I get the original contents of the model before the changes are made in the admin page, so I can persist them in the history table? Using the above example, I want the `amount` field in `EstimateHistory` to be 1500.00, not 1700.00.

I'm new to Django (and even Python), so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the common way is to use the model `__init__()` to memorize what value was there. Like this(rough example without testing):

```
class Estimate(Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Estimate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # use a different name to record what the old value is
        self.initial_amount = self.amount

    def make_history(self):
        old_value = self.initial_amount
        new_value = self.amount
        # etc etc
```

I don't particularly like the way to record history as above because it's cumbersome, every time you track history you have to write something like this. For my own project I use [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history), it's so easy to use for tracking history. You don't need to do any of the stuff I mentioned above and you can track any model history you want.

Comment: For some reason I'd convinced myself that I didn't want to implement a canned solution, but sure enough, `django-simple-history` was easy enough to implement so I went ahead with that. Thanks!